# How to add app to suggested apps for custom location in IOS 8?

Tags: geolocation, ios8

I want to create app with simple useful information, but I want this app will be shown **as suggested app** (according new feature in IOS 8) on some **custom location**. Is it possible to do?
And anyway how can I add my app to suggested apps to any location? Can developer make smth for that or it's kind of automatic by Apple? Thanks for any answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recently ran into the same set of question.

Below is a copy of the response I received from the Apple Developer Support Team. For a detailed look at my original question to them, please have a look at my answer here on SO:

[iOS 8 Suggested Apps - How does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26680439/ios-8-suggested-apps-how-does-it-work/26680440#26680440)

---

Hello,

Location relevant Apps are recommended on the lock screen and in the App Store based on a number of factors, including their popularity at the location, and there is no mechanism or process by which an App developer can add their App to the list of recommended Apps.

However, if your iOS App is directly related to the location or venue (such as a mall guide iOS App which is published by the mall owner or operator), and you believe your iOS App’s relevance warrants it being included the list of recommended Apps, then you are encouraged to submit an enhancement request via http://bugreport.apple.com/, and request that Apple consider whether your iOS App should be included in the list of recommended Apps for that location.

You should provide as much detail in the ’enhancement request' about the App and venue/location as possible, such as the App ID, App Name, URL to the App on the App Store, venue name, venue location (address & lat/lon), the relevance (if any) of your iOS App to the venue/location, and relationship (if any) between you as the developer and the owner/operator of the venue/location.

Submission of an enhancement request does not guarantee that a particular iOS App will be added to the list of recommended Apps for a venue or location, and the sole feedback from Apple on the request will come through the http://bugreport.apple.com/ bug report system.

Regards,

Apple Developer Technical Support